# What is workload throttling?

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, throttling, workload-scheduler, workload

Could somebody give a good explanation for newbie, what does following phrase means:

> 1) workload throttling within a single cluster and 2) workload
>   balance across multiple clusters.

This is from overview of advantages of one ETL-jobs tool, that helps perform ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) jobs on Redshift database.

Comment: Please narrow the scope of your question.  What don't you understand?  There are too many ways to answer this and some of them may just be regurgitation of what you already aren't understanding.

Comment: @zero298 I don't understand the phrase " workload throttling" in general and in terms of Redshift cluster

Answer (score 2):

Many web services allocate a maximum amount of "interaction" that you can have with a service.  Once your exceed that amount, the service will shift in how it completes its interactions.

Amazon imposes limitations on how much compute power you can consume within your nodes.  The phrase "workload throttling" means that if you exceed the limits detailed in Amazon's documentation [Amazon Redshift Limts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html), your queries, jobs, tasks, or work items will be given lower priority or fail outright.

The idea is that Amazon doesn't want you to consume so much compute power that it prevents others from using the service and, honestly, they don't want you to consume more power than it costs them to provide.

Workload throttling isn't an idea exclusive to this Amazon service, or cloud services in general.  The concept can be found in any system that needs to account for receiving more tasks than it can handle.  Some systems deal with being overburdened differently.

For example, some systems will defer you to alternate services in the case of a load balancer.  3rd party data APIs will delegate you a maximum amount of data per hour/minute and then either delay the responses you get back, charge you more money, or stop responding altogether.

---

Another service that you can look at that deals with throttling is the Google Maps Geocoding service.  If you look on their documentation, [Google Maps Geocoding API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits), you will see that:

> Users of the standard API:
>
> - 2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
> - 50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

If you exceed this and have billing enabled, Google will shift to:

> $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily.

I can't remember what the response looks like after you hit that daily limit, but once you hit it, you basically don't get responses back until the day resets.